# Python selenium keep browser open

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium to open some browser windows for marketing reasons. I simply open my marketing sources, login via selenium and start working.

The problem is, that after the code is executed selenium closes the window.

All solutions havent helped much so far.

I have 13 browser windows atm., which look like this:

```
def open_instagram():    
    try:
        # Connect
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
        browser = webdriver.Chrome('drivers/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
        browser.set_window_size(1800, 900)
        browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=de")
        browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'username').send_keys('MYEMAIL', Keys.TAB, 'MYPW', Keys.ENTER)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e, 'Instagram')

open_instagram()
```

The closest solution which I found is adding this at the end of my script, but somehow it will only keep 5 windows open, than close 5 windows and open next 5 new windows:

```
while True:
    pass
```

I just want that selenium keeps all browser windows open, until I close them manually.

Comment: If you need this to hand-weave scraping code, you'll have better results with an interactive session: you'll be able to interact with the browser both by hand (to get XPaths, ids and such) and with commands.

Comment: How's that @ivan_pozdeev, how do I create an interactive session?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you want chrome and chromedriver to stay open, you have to use the 'detach' option when starting chromedriver.

In your case add :

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

before you pass in the options to the browser

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('drivers/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
```

**Or** you can run the code in debug mode with breakpoint at the end and when it pauses 'kill' the program and take over the browser if you want to, but this works in IDE only.

Update: As of Jan. 24, `chrome_options` parameter when initializing Webdriver is now only "`options`".

Comment: You also need from "selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options"

Comment: Is it possible to reuse this browser window? E.g. get the PID or something and use explicitly if exists?

Comment: With Python you use `chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)`, with C# you use the `ChromeOptions.LeaveBrowserOpen` property... either way tho neither of them will function until you add `options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation")` to your options setup.

Comment: `("detach", True)`  option only works on terminal. It doesn't work when debugging in VSCode

Comment: To exclude `enable-automation` (that hides the "Chrome is being controlled by automated software banner" banner, and maybe does other things, but does not actually disable automation) in Python, use `chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])`

Comment: 'chrome_options' is deprecated, use 'options' instead like so:
`browser = webdriver.Chrome('drivers/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)`

Answer (score 8):

You can also add `global browser` like so:

```py
def open_instagram():    
    try:
        # Connect
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
        global browser # this will prevent the browser variable from being garbage collected
        browser = webdriver.Chrome('drivers/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
        browser.set_window_size(1800, 900)
        browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=de")
        browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'username').send_keys('MYEMAIL', Keys.TAB, 'MYPW', Keys.ENTER)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e, 'Instagram')

open_instagram()
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956906/7487335)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this would be just to add `input()` after your get function. This will prompt you to have to press the Enter key to continue and will thus keep your program from finishing. It might work more considering you seem to be manually shifting through each webpage?
Alternatively you can stop it from closing using the `time.sleep` function in the time module, but that isn't efficient for keeping it open indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

detach options is right way to solve your problem

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 4 / PHP / Docker

`$this->driver = RemoteWebDriver::createBySessionID(self::$session_id, self::$server, 60000, 60000);`

```
version: "3.5"
#Latest version
networks:
  grid-network:

services:

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:latest
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4446:4444"
    networks:
      - grid-network
      
  chrome:
    shm_size: 4gb 
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    container_name: chrome
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - NODE_MAX_SESSION=5
      - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=5
      - GRID_MAX_SESSION=31556926
      - GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT=31556926
      - GRID_TIMEOUT=31556926
      - GRID_SESSION_TIMEOUT=31556926
      - SESSION_TIMEOUT=31556926
      - NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT=31556926
      - GRID_CLEAN_UP_CYCLE=31556926
      - SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT=31556926
      - SE_SESSION_REQUEST_TIMEOUT=31556926
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "33333:5900"
      - "3333:7900"
      - "44444:4444"
    links:
      - selenium-hub
    networks:
      - grid-network
```