# Keep Selenium driver open in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I have searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865300/pytthon-selenium-keep-browser-open) for Python.

Is there a way to keep the driver bot open after executing the code?

I know I can use Stop at the end but I am searching for that direct way to end the code and at the same time keep the browser open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked around and it is solved by declaring the driver in the declaration section

```
Private bot As New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Test1()
bot.get "https://www.google.com"
End Sub

Sub Test2()
bot.get "https://www.facebook.com"
End Sub

Sub QuitBott()
bot.Quit
Set bot = Nothing
End Sub
```

But I welcome any other solutions

Comment: Tests should be run independently. Each test should have its own browser instance to better insulate each script run.

Comment: @JeffC Thanks a lot for reply. The target is to keep the browser open regardless to navigate to other urls. If there is a way better, I would welcome other solutions