# After executing selenium python code google chrome closes automatically

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**This code runs without any error but it automatically closes the google chrome after searching w3school**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def google():
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys('w3school')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

google()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python selenium keep browser open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865300/python-selenium-keep-browser-open)

Comment: Can't reproduce. Is that the exact code? do you have `driver.close()/driver.quit()` somewhere?

Comment: Are you waiting for the last action to complete (and then presumably asserting on a condition)?

Answer (score 12):

Try the experimental options provided in the webdriver like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="path/to/executable")
```

**Caveat**: This does leave chrome tabs open and detached, which you will have to manually close afterwards

Answer (score 3):

you must open a browser instance outside the function so it will remain open after executing the codes inside the function

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")    

def google():
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys('w3school')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

google()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because "driver" variable is local variable in your function, so when the function have done, the "driver" variable will be remove and then the browser close automatically.

=> Solution is you set "driver" is global variable in your program.

Answer (score 0):

I use the chromedriver to open chrome.

1. download the chrome driver based on your chrome version.
2. unzip the chrome driver to the below path in your C drive.
3. Then use the below code to open the chrome webpage.

```
chromepath = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case the version of chrome driver needed to be replaced by currenct version of my chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Using Edge, i didn't find the option "executable_path" to follow the steps Prithu Srinivas gave, but using the code below, the window stoped closing automatically:

```
options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

browser = webdriver.Edge(options=options, keep_alive=True)
```

The same goes if i don't use the argument "keep_alive=True".