# Chrome quits after running .py file using Webdriver

Tags: pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

### Below are the statements of my .py file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
webdriver.Chrome()
```

---

Chrome starts and then quits immediately if I run these statements together in Pycharm as a .py file. The same happens if I copy paste the two statements and run them together in Pycharm's Python Console. Strangely, his does not happen when using Python3 in terminal or if I'm executing just the webdriver.Chrome() statement alone after importing the Selenium library. Can't tell if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900800/after-executing-selenium-python-code-google-chrome-closes-automatically

Comment: @vaeVictis Thanks!