# how to open new tab with new data? [Selenium-Python]

Tags: python, selenium

i made auto login bot with selenium. its getting data from .txt file and input.
my question is : how can i open new tab with new user:pass?
for example first line of .txt file is test:test and i want to open new tab with second line of txt ( test2:test2 )

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time


browser = webdriver.Chrome()

def checker(data):
    email = data[0]
    password = data[1]
    
    browser.get(
    "site name")

    browser.find_element_by_id("login-username").send_keys(email)
    browser.find_element_by_id("login-password").send_keys(password)
    browser.find_element_by_id("login-button").click()

    time.sleep(5)

    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("._95e9f2bdf9c64702a").click()

combos = open("combo.txt", "r").readlines()
arrange = [lines.replace("\n", "")for lines in combos]
for lines in arrange:
    data = lines.split(":")
    checker(data)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open web in new tab Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python)

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/51865955/12870513

Comment: @Karthik thank you but i guess keys not working.