# Python Selenium unrecognized chrome option: detach

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I'm following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865300/python-selenium-keep-browser-open).

But I get the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: cannot parse capability: goog:chromeOptions
from invalid argument: unrecognized chrome option: detach
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct way of adding this options is

```
chrome_options.set_capability("detach", True)
```