# Chrome closing immediately using simple Selenium script

Tags: python, selenium

This is literally all my code is- followed a beginner tutorial [video](https://youtu.be/pUUhvJvs-R4?t=309)

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'http://google.com'

driver.get(url)
```

It's supposed to open chrome and remain open, but it closes immediately. When I use time.sleep(10) it does stay for 10 seconds, but closes after. How can I keep the browser until I close it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python selenium keep browser open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865300/python-selenium-keep-browser-open)

Answer (score 0):

Solved - for some reason some unused "import" lines at the top of the code were the issue. I deleted them