# Chrome Webdriver automatically closes after the code is run in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I am currently learning Selenium and when i run the code, Chrome Appears and after execution it automatically closes..How to avoid it ?

Also is it necessary to put Application.wait in Chrome or the  code runs only after complete execution of a single line and so on ?

```
   Dim Browser As Selenium.ChromeDriver
   
   Set Browser = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
   
   Browser.Get "https://www.google.com"
   Browser.Window.Maximize
   Browser.FindElementById("userName").SendKeys Sheet1.Range("B2")

End Sub
```

Comment: Refer this for your first question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72402033/chrome-browser-closes-after-running-selenium-chrome-webdriver?rq=2

Comment: instead of `Dim...` put `Private Browser As Selenium.ChromeDriver` at the top of the module (outside of the sub).