# Why is chrome closing? Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = chrome_path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.example.com/login.phtml")
form = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[name='f']")
username_input = form.find_element_by_name("username")
password_input = form.find_element_by_name("pw")
username_input.send_keys("LOGIN")
password_input.send_keys("PASSWORD")
form.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
if driver.current_url == "https://www.example.com/index.phtml":
    print("Successful login!")
else:
    print("Login failed")
```

Before i had

```
driver.quit()
```

at the end of the code, removing it didn't solve the problem

Comment: It doesn't even open the website, the bar only shows:
  date:,
https://i.imgur.com/TylFCug.jpg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51865955/494134

Answer (score 0):

Use time.sleep() or WebDriverWait from selenium.webdriver.support.ui to wait for page to be fully loaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


chrome_path = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = chrome_path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.example.com/login.phtml")

# Wait for the page to fully load before interacting with the page
time.sleep(5)

form = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[name='f']")
username_input = form.find_element_by_name("username")
password_input = form.find_element_by_name("pw")
username_input.send_keys("LOGIN")
password_input.send_keys("PASSWORD")
form.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
if driver.current_url == "https://www.example.com/index.phtml":
    print("Successful login!")
else:
    print("Login failed")
```

Comment: This question is about the browser closing at the end of the program (which is normal behavior for Selenium).  How does this answer help with that?

Comment: @JohnGordon This did not fix his problem, but it will help him start working with selenium. Yes, browser closing at the end of the program is normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = WebDriver(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.example.com/login.phtml")
username_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id")
password_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "pw")
username_input.send_keys("LOGIN")
password_input.send_keys("PASSWORD")
login_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.bxpad.ttup")
login_button.click()
sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```