# My Selenium scripts in VScode are closing before i can do aynthing on the website it opened

Tags: python, selenium

So for about a week ive had this problem where all my selenium files (previously worked fine) are now closing itself the same second the website it opened fully loads. there is no

```
driver.quit()
```

in my script so this shouldnt be happening right?

I have tried reinstalling everything and even went as far as reinstalling windows thinking it was somehow corrupting the files but nothing worked. As anyone experienced this? also adding time.sleep doesnt seem to help aswell

Comment: I experienced this today, and was due to the Selenium script being within a function. 
I don't know why it was closing, but once I took the script out of the function, it worked fine. Not sure if this could be the cause of your issue ?

Comment: Also this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865300/python-selenium-keep-browser-open