# Python selenium chrome/chromium browser quits automatically at the end

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I just started to learn Python + selenium.

Here's my setup:

- chromium version: `103.0.5046.0`
- chromedriver version: `103.0.5046.0`
- chrome version: `122.0.6261.70`

Here's my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
options.binary_location = r'D:\fewst\Downloads\Win_x64_1000027_chrome-win\chrome-win/chrome.exe'
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

**I just want the website to remain open and stay that way at the end of my script.**

I don't want the browser to close automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Once the program ends, the process exits and the selenium goes down. Your solution here is to delay the process. For this you could either use `input()`, which waits for an input in the terminal, or the `time.sleep()` function to run the program for a longer period.

Example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = r'D:\fewst\Downloads\Win_x64_1000027_chrome-win\chrome-win/chrome.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

input() # dont enter any unless you want to shut it down
```

Comment: but i don't understand why i try it first time, it doesn't work.i  built a new folder,with same code,it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `breakpoint()` is the best practice for pausing a Python script (for Python 3.7 or newer). Type `c` and press Enter to continue from the `breakpoint()`.

An example of one in a [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) script:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver()
driver.open("seleniumbase.io/demo_page")
driver.highlight("h2")
driver.type("#myTextInput", "Automation")
driver.click("#checkBox1")
driver.highlight("img", loops=6)

breakpoint()  # Type "c" and press Enter to continue

driver.quit()
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76916972/7058266

Answer (score 0):

If you want the browser to remain open after the Google page is launched, You just need to add the below line:

```
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

Like below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
options.binary_location = r'D:\fewst\Downloads\Win_x64_1000027_chrome-win\chrome-win/chrome.exe'
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77402087/7598774

Comment: i tried it four times,but it doesn't work.In fact,i saw several same answers in other questions.why i can't use this way to solve the problem.